# Retrofit for Android: How to create class to map to returned data

Tags: android, retrofit

Using Retrofit for Android I'm successfully connecting to a web service with a login and password:

```
getService().doSignIn( m_editEmail.getText().toString(), m_editPwd.getText().toString(),new Callback<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Object login, Response response) {

    }
    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

    }
});
```

You may ask why am I using Object and not a class? Well, I could not get any return data unless I used the generic Object class. I tried to create a class with the property names I expected to get back but couldn't get it to work (just empty values for the class's properties would be returned).
So now when I use Object I get data back but its in the LinkedTreeMap type like this:

```
 root  // this is of type com.google.json.internal.LinkedTreeMap
    [0] 
        key
        value  // this is of type com.google.json.internal.LinkedTreeMap
             [0] REsult Code - > 0
             [1] Result Message -> success
             [2] ...
```

So basically it is returning a LinkedTreeMap within a LinkedTreeMap ---How can I map this to a class with matching properties for easier retrieval?

Comment: Did you try Response?

Comment: Nothing of use in response

Comment: What happens if you make login a Response object

Comment: Doesn't work -- anyway 1st param is supposed to be your callback Class according to Retrofit docs.